# UITableViewCell backgroundView not stretched

Tags: ios, uitableview, stretch

I'm trying to set a stretched background picture on the back of a `UITableViewCell`.
It's a common question, answered many times, so I'm doing it the "standard way" :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell;
  UIImage* bgImg;

  bgImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bg_selected.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 1, 0)]; //top/left/bottom/right
  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImg]];
  return cell;
}
```

If I simply try this, I obtain a tiled background.
After reading several similar questions/answers, I did try :

- Forcing scale of the background View : `cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;`
- Force resizing of background view : `cell.backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;`
- Set autoresize of the mask : `cell.backgroundView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`;
- Trying for force the frame size of the background `UIImageView`

It appears that my background picture is partially stretched up to a predetermined size, then tiled (not enough reputation yet to upload images, sorry ...) :

- vertical stretch is partial and doesn't use full height
- horizontal stretch is partial and doesn't use full width

The background picture is a 6x3 pixels image (with a blue vertical line on the left, a dark gray back and a light gray horizontal line at the bottom).

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

**[Edit]**
In fact the problem doesn't seems to be a UIEdgeInsetsMake problem.
When using  bgImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bg_selected.png"]; the background image is still not filling the complete cell background.

Comment: cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

Comment: Ok I got it, I need to use the resizingMode argument :  ` bgImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bg_selected.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 1, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];`

Comment: I'll answer my own question with a full answer asap (not allowed to do it yet). Thanks for your suggestions everyone !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 1, 0)
```

Basically you say i want a stretchable image but i don't want the bottom line to stretch neither the left border. That does not make any sense. Your edge insets must leave some stretchable parts. For instance if your image is 6x3 you could have :

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

However you might want to redesign your image before.

Comment: In fact I think this means "Do not stretch 5 pixels on the left and the pixel at the bottom" The bottom and left "non-stretchable" zones will be tiled when the rest of the background will be stretched. Am I wrong with that ? Anyway I tried your suggestion : The partial vertical stretch is lost and image is fully tiled without any stretch.

Comment: I believe you're wrong, using this function, the picture is supposed to stretch, not to tile. If you want to stretch i believe you must leave a stretchable part (meaning without any cap) Have you tried with the code i've just edited ?

Comment: Yes, just tried ! It doesn't fix the problem, the background image is stretched differently but still doest fill the complete cell background ...

Comment: I believe you have two problems. The stretch is different because your image should probably not be the same as the one you used. The fact that it does not fill the complete background is something else.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for `UIImage`.

```
UIIMage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bg_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15  topCapHeight:15];
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to fix it. My background image is 6x3 pixels, so having a top and left margin of 15 seems obvious.

Comment: It was not a problem of Cap value. By the way, stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth is deprecated since iOS 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I got it !

The problem was that my background picture was only partially stretched and then tiled in order to fill the complete cell (whatever the UIEdgeInsetsMake parameter was).

I succeeded by using : resizableImageWithCapInsets and **specifying the resizingMode argument**.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell;

  UIImage* bgImg;
  bgImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bg_selected.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 1, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImg]];
  return cell;
}
```

Thanks to all for your suggestions !